# Reading from a txt file in 68k

Tags: assembly, easy68k

I got stuck in a simple 68k program.

Program needs to read from a txt file. In txt file are numbers, separated by space, and file ends with a dot (.)

I need to enter a file name and read from it, count how many numbers are there and sum up all neighbour numbers.

Example: 222 10 300 7 450 201 9 117 38 456.
Result: Sum of neighbours: 232 310 307 457 651 210 126 155 494,
Number of numbers: 10.

Here's what I've got so far.
Using D3 for number of numbers.

```
START   ORG $1000

    MOVE #0,D3

    MOVE #14,D0
    LEA text,A1
    TRAP #15

    MOVE #2,D0
    LEA name,A1
    TRAP #15

    MOVE #51,D0
    LEA name,A1
    TRAP #15

    MOVE    #53,D0
    MOVE.L  #100,D2
    LEA cont,A1
    TRAP    #15

    MOVE #13,D0
    TRAP    #15

loop    CMP.B #$2E,(A1)
    BEQ dot
    CMP.B #$20,(A1)
    BEQ space


    ADD.L   #1,A1
    JMP loop

space ADD.L #1,D3
    RTS

dot MOVE #14,D0
    LEA sum,A1
    TRAP #15

    LEA end,A1
    TRAP #15
    MOVEA d3,a1
    TRAP    #15

    MOVE.B #9,D0
    TRAP #15

name DS.B 10
cont DS.B 100
text DC.B 'Enter file name:',0
sum DC.B 'Sum of neighbours: ',0
end DC.B 'Number of numbers: ',0

    END START
```

First of all, what is the easiest way to print my d3 register on screen?
2nd: Since im moving only one character at the time, how do i make a number from those 1-3 characters?

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet.

Comment: Well, first of all, what is the easiest way to print my d3 register on screen?
2nd: Since im moving only one character at the time, how do i make a number from those 1-3 characters?

Comment: Please put the question in the body. not in a comment. I don't know 68k assembly, just trying to help you write a good question.